# How to map a collection with multiple join columns on multiple tables?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a set of 4 tables setup like the following:

```
Table parent_a
id | other_columns...

Table parent_b
id | filter | other_columns...

Table child_a
id | parent_id | other_columns...

Table child_b
id | filter | other_columns...
```

The entities are setup as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent_a")
@SecondaryTable(name = "parent_b")
public class Parent {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  @Column(name = "id")
  private Integer id;

  @Column(name = "filter", table = "parent_b")
  private String filter;

  @OneToMany
  @JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id"),
    @JoinColumn(name = "filter", table = "child_b")
  })
  private List<Child> children;
  // Mappings for other columns, getters/setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "child_a")
@SecondaryTable(name = "child_b")
public class Child {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  @Column(name = "id")
  private Integer id;

  @Column(name = "filter", table = "child_b")
  private String filter;
  // Mappings for other columns, getters/setters
}
```

When I deploy my application I get the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.cfg.NotYetImplementedException: Collections having FK in secondary table
```

Is there another way to get the parent entity populated with the child entities filtered based on the parent filter?

Answer (score 0):

I used an entity listener to populate the collection on load of the parent entity.